# He acts as if he owns (vs owned) the place?

Tags: verbs

*He acts **as if** he **owns** (vs **owned**) the place?*

Said to describe a popular boy at a school who behaves in a too confident way. -- his peers say that.

Both versions seem to be popular. Why is that so? Shouldn't it be grammar-wise "owned"?

Comment: **acts** is present tense, so **owns** is a better match, instead of past-tense **owned**.

Answer (score 7):

There's been [a significant usage shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acts%20as%20if%20he%20owned%2Cacts%20as%20if%20he%20owns&year_start=1880&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) over the past century.

[image]

Presumably a century ago people thought of the ***as if*** component in this construction as a reference to a *counterfactual* situation (as in *if I **were** a rich man*). Today we tend to think in terms of "parallel" tenses in ***acts*** and ***owns***. But consider...

> *"Please lend me £10..."*
> 1: *"**If** we **were** friends I'd lend it to you"*
> 2: *"It's not **as if** we **were** friends, so I won't"*
> 3: *"It's not **as if** we **are** friends, so I won't"*

...where #2 *doesn't* start with *It **wasn't** as if...*, but I personally would *definitely* prefer #2 over #3, regardless of the apparent mismatch of tenses. I don't have any special preference for ***owns*** or ***owned*** in OP's cited example, though. They both sound fine to me.

---

Thanks to [@Jack](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332362/he-acts-as-if-he-owns-vs-owned-the-place/332368#comment629376_332367) for a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Fake_tense) to where it says...

> *In many languages, **counterfactuality** is marked by **past tense morphology***.

Comment: Very interesting! Like you, I have no preference for _owns/owned_, but in the lending example, I have a clear preference for #3 over #2. I don’t perceive that as a counterfactual statement at all – the tense in that example is semantic to me (i.e., “It’s not as if we were friends at the time” vs “It’s not as if we’re friends right now”), and the subjunctive is blocked (“It’s not as if he was my friend”, but not “*It’s not as if he were my friend”). More commonly, I’d use _like_, where the preference is even stronger: “*It’s not like we were friends right now” is actually ungrammatical to me.

Comment: Yes, there's obviously an area of uncertainty here. Which I think stands to reason, given the charted usage shift. Different speakers will lean to a greater or lesser extent to the "Past Tense = conterfactual" or the "Tense consistency is paramount" side of things. I lean towards your perrspective with that ***right now*** example, but I find I can tolerate *As college roommates we were quite close - but it's not as if we were friends today, so I refused to lend him the money.*

Answer (score 0):

Although 'owned' can be used to mean the present status of something that is owned (eg *the house is owned by him*), when it has a direct object the verb has to use the correct tense, and so should use the same tense as the word 'acts':

- He acts as if he owns the place.
- He acted as if he owned the place.

And of course, the tense of the entire sentence should reflect whether you were talking about how he acted in the past, or how he acts presently, or in general.

The idiom does have many more variations though, and where it could become more complex (and cause confusion among native speakers) is if you introduced a hypothetical into it, for example, "*you would think he owned the place from the way he acts*". In such a case, 'owned' is the correct tense for a hypothetical statement. I can't really explain any apparent major shift in usage except to say that (i) sometimes native speakers do get idioms wrong, and (ii) possibly the hypothetical nature of it is confusing some.

Comment: OP already knows about the "consistent tense" aspect. This answer doesn't address the issue of why so many speakers ignore that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nor does your answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Fake_tense